# Stacking and delaying multiple UI change notifications

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, asynchronous

Did anyone handle such scenario in the code?

User is typing something in the input area (say, rich text box). This causes multiple TextChanged events to fire. We want to capture only last changed event when user stops typing (i.e.: no changed events for 5 seconds).

Does anyone have a clean C# snippet of doing that?

Comment: I would love to know reason for the downvote.

Comment: How do you _really_ know when they user has stopped typing? And if there's a delay after they've stopped, will they start typing again to see if the application's frozen (firing off more keystrokes)?

Comment: It's ok to consider that user has stopped typing for some time, if he has not been typing for 2 seconds (or whatever predefined interval). The purpose is to prevent wave of events propagating through the UI (when such handling is expensive)

Comment: Oh, I completely understand. It's just that it's hard to anticipate what a user is going to do next. I prefer to try to mold the interface to the data and offer a choice that will reduce my work (and their confusion), say, for example, a drop-down list instead of a textbox (this is a very simple example; you'd probably have to create your own ui for your particular situation, but it might be better than what you're doing now).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any .NET controls that would work just like text boxes from the Google Wave demo :)

Comment: Since you have to use a timer (and are using asp.net), what about setTimeout in js?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean ASP.NET, but rather the righ UI frameworks (Forms, SL, WPF, GTK etc)

Comment: typo in my previous comment: "rich"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `Timer` with an interval of five (or whatever) seconds, and, in your `TextChanged` event, stop the timer and start it again.  Then, move your handler code to the timer's `Tick` event.

Comment: +1. I was just typing the same answer. I did this just today. I found that the best delay is 500ms

Comment: The delay would depend on what you're doing in the event.

Comment: Yes, that's the design I've been considering, too. Unfortunately Timer class is bound to Windows.Forms (and optimized for that, too). And general guideline for multi-UI MVC is that controllers are not bound to the UI framework...

Comment: Use System.Timers.Timer instead; it's not bound to WinForms.  Remember, though, that it will raise the event on a different thread.

Comment: Alternatively, put the timer in the view (or, perhaps, combine it with the textbox in a reusable component) and call the controller from the timer's Tick event.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after using  System.Threading.Timer as suggested by **SLaks**, I've got this extremely simple snippet:

```
public sealed class CallBuffer : IDisposable
{

    private readonly TimeSpan _timeSpan;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public CallBuffer(Action call, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        _timeSpan = timeSpan;
        _timer = new Timer(state => call());
    }

    public void Buffer()
    {
        _timer.Change(_timeSpan, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Did I miss something here?

One note, is that it does not care about the UI thread (caller should pass proper invocation) and this allows to separate this code from the views.

Comment: Since you don't have a finalizer, you don't need to call GC.SuppressFinalize(this); in Dispose.  Also, never implement Dispose explicitly.

Comment: Also, it might be easier to use System.Timers.Timer (not System.Threading.Timer); if you do, call Stop(), then Start() in Buffer().

Comment: Slaks - why not IDisposable explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CustomTextBox.aspx) looks promising.

> I was creating another control, a
>   pager control to be exact, and ran
>   into a problem. The problem was that
>   when a user would type in for example
>   100 to navigate to that page, I was
>   trapping the TextChanged event and it
>   would first go to page 1, then page
>   10, then page 100(get the mental
>   picture). I didn't want this to happen
>   for a couple of reasons but the main
>   one is because I'm not storing data of
>   each page in memory and it gets
>   populated when the page is selected
>   from a SQL server, so I wanted to
>   eliminate 3 queries when one is needed
>   for the example previously mentioned.
>
> So I decided that instead of adding a
>   "go" or "refresh" button to my pager
>   control, I would delay the TextBox
>   TextChanged event so as long as the
>   user was typing it would not fire the
>   event until he/she was done(delay
>   threshold was met).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `Leave` event, which should fire when the user tabs out of the control.

Obviously, this depends on what the control is doing and what the users expect.